# Formula manipulation in R

Tags: r, formulas

I'm trying to do something similar to the `MASS:stepAIC` function, for Gaussian models with both fixed and mixed effects. The idea is to make it completely generalizable to many fixed and mixed effects, since these tasks can be performed by hand trivially for a few.

I want to be able to write the formula as the input as you would for lmer:

`Y ~ x1 + x2 + (a|b) + (1|c)

I am unable to extract the information I need from the formula class. In addition I will need to be able to put a select number of the variable back into the lm and lmer functions. So I want to be able to extract the parts of the formula into:

```
data      fixed effects       mixed effects
Y              x1                 a|b
               x2                 1|c
```

I then need to be able to send an arbitrary set of fixed and mixed effects automatically to lm:

`lm(y ~ x1)`

Comment: Are there always two of each of fixed and mixed effects? How flexible do you want it? Are the mixed effects always of the form (a|b)?

Comment: You might want to start by looking at the internals of the (private) `lme4:::drop1.mer` function in the `lme4` package ...

Comment: @Spacedman , I want it to be as generalizable as possible. Currently I don't have any mixed effects more complicated than a|b, so this would be the desired initial level the achieve. Thanks.

Comment: Another example to look at is latticeParseFormula in the lattice package. What I'm concerned about is how your formula can tell which element is which part of your model. Y is easy, because its on the LHS, but to R the RHS is just a sum of equivalent things. The nlme function has several formula parameters to specify each part of the model - maybe that's the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can assume precisely the form `(variable|variable)` for the mixed effect terms then:

```
library(gsubfn)
fo <- Y ~ x1 + x2 + (a|b) + (1|c)

mixed.vec <- strapplyc(format(fo), "[(] *(\\w+) *[|] *(\\w+) *[)]")[[1]]
mixed <- matrix(mixed.vec, byrow = TRUE, nc = 2)
fixed <- setdiff(all.vars(fo)[-1], mixed)
```

which gives the following:

```
> mixed
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "b" 
[2,] "1"  "c" 
> fixed
[1] "x1" "x2"
```

Here `mixed` is a matrix whose first column holds the variables before the | and the second column holds the corresponding variables after the | .

Comment: This is great. Just one point I found that if the formula is too long format breaks it into multiple lines and so can break mixed effects. this can be got around using as.character(fo)[3] instead.

Comment: And its complete, thanks so much, can now take any glm which glm, and glmer in lme4 can solve for and perform a forward fitting procedure, printing out all the steps for transparency, and saving a lot of work doing it laboriously...